# Modelsim: resume simulation future

Tags: vhdl, verilog, simulation, modelsim

I have long running simulation in Modelsim for VHDL/Verilog designs.
I want to know are there any way to save current simulation progress and resume it somehow in later time?

Answer (score 2):

The ModelSim command `checkpoint` will save simulator state and  the `restore` command will restore it. Here's a [link](http://www.pldworld.com/_hdl/2/_ref/se_html/manual_html/a_tnt2.html) for details on using the commands.

You can restore between simulations or within the current simulation. Several things will be saved using `checkpoint`, however others, like TCL macro state, manual command-line changes, GUI window state and statistics will *not* be saved.

You can save waveform or list GUI window state using `write format <list | wave> <filename>` and recall the state with `do <filename>`, as seen [here](http://www.pldworld.com/_hdl/2/_ref/se_html/manual_html/c_vcmds197.html).

Comment: A link-only answer is not very useful, as the link can break and then the answer is useless. Please try to summarize the information that the OP needs.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson - good point. Edited with more detail so it's not just a link answer.